Clover Sandbox Payment Integration
I am following the Clover Documentation which works up until the creation of checkout when I enter card details provided by Clover it says:

Payment not successful, please try again.

This is the error in the log:
{
  "status": {
    "reason": "Bad Request",
    "code": 400
  },
  "message": "Invalid input",
  "errors": [{
    "field": "currency",
    "error": "Invalid currency present on auth payment request."
  }]
}

I am sending post request to https://sandbox.dev.clover.com/invoicingcheckoutservice/v1/checkouts with the following data:
{
  "customer": {
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "email": "test@example.com"
  },
  "shoppingCart": {
    "orderNote": "Test Order",
    "lineItems": [{
      "name": "itemA",
      "unitQty": 1,
      "price": 100
    }]
  },
  "currency": "GBP", 
  "orderNote": "Test Order"
}

I get success response using the above data, as below:
{
  "href": "https://sandbox.dev.clover.com/checkout/abcID...",
  "checkoutSessionId": "abcID...",
  "expirationTime": "2024-09-13T10:51:58.962+0000",
  "createdTime": "2024-09-13T10:36:58.986+0000"
}

When I open the checkout form and enter card details it gives above error mentioned.
The payload generated seems right:
{
  source: "clv_abc", 
  sourceType: "CARD",
  //...
}
customer: {
  firstName: "abc", 
  lastName: "abc", 
  phoneNumber: "", 
  email: "",
  //...
}
orderNote: "" //shows blank
source: "clv_abc.."
sourceType: "CARD" 


The error seems clearly explained in the log, 'Invalid currency present on auth payment request' - you have not set a currency. You've only set the price of the line item

@RoryMcCrossan Even if I set the currency as "GBP" it gives the same error
